How much pressure would it take to compress an object to electron degenerate matter?
If somebody with telekinetic powers were to crush an object until it was electron degenerate matter how much pressure would need to be applied?  I know the answer will almost certainly vary depending on the material of the initial object in question, so for ease of calculation lets say its made of pure carbon.  I tried looking on Wikipedia for the answer, but the page only gave me some equations that I couldn't make heads or tails of.
Why electron degenerate matter?  I feel like electron degenerate matter is almost always overlooked in favor of the more EXTREME neutron degenerate matter & black holes.  I would like to try and fill in some of that knowledge gap.
Bonus question:
What happens when he "lets go", would it lose stability & start exploding like neutron degenerate matter?

You don't need telekinetic powers. You just need to bury the matter under enough matter that gravity crushes it.

If you want to fill in the knowledge gap you should be able to put in the numbers in the wiki article

Your usual solids are already electron degenerate matter. They certainly are always that in metals.
